# AutoIt _ArraySort(..) function not sorting correctly

Tags: arrays, sorting, quicksort, autoit

I am working on an AutoIt script that will take in a text file. The text file is made up of a series of test results in groups of 5 lines. This script is to go through the file and output the median score for each group. the score is displayed after the 11th "*,*". For example with this sample file:

```
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,100.2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,300.2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,160.2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,301.2
a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,a,161.2

b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,110.5
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,87.5
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,89.5
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,190.5
b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,b,170.5

c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,90.2
c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,190.2
c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,40.2
c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,20.2
c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,c,80.2
```

I am expecting median scores of 161.2, 110.5 and 80.2 for groups a, b and c respectively. However, the output result is as follows:

```
median is = 161.2 ----- sorted array : 100.2 , 160.2 , 161.2 , 300.2 , 301.2
median is = 190.5 ----- sorted array : 110.5 , 170.5 , 190.5 , 87.5 , 89.5
median is = 40.2 ----- sorted array : 190.2 , 20.2 , 40.2 , 80.2 , 90.2
```

The first group gets sorted correctly but after that the array is no longer being sorted. And this is despite `_ArraySort(...)` being called directly before the output. Any idea why this could be happening?

The code is as follows:

```vb
Func CondenseResults()

    $size = 5   ;temporary, variable to be passed on from other function

    $gameDetail = ""
    $rawResult = "D:\RTG_Benchmark\results\results.txt"
    local $openResults = FileOpen("D:\RTG_Benchmark\results\results2.txt", 1)
    Local $i = 1
    Local $j = 0
    Local $spaceCount = 0
    Local $score[$size]
    Local $runMultiplier[2]     ; 0 = previous, 1 = current
    Local $subString

    Do
        $resultLine = FileReadLine($rawResult, $i)      ; read line from raw result
        $subString =  StringSplit($resultLine,",")  ; split
        If StringLen($resultLine) = 0 Then
            $spaceCount += 1
            $j = 0
            FileWriteLine ( $openResults, "" & @CRLF)
        Else
            $gameDetail = $subString[1] & $subString[2] & $subString[3] & $subString[4] & $subString[5] & $subString[6] & $subString[7] & $subString[8] & $subString[9] & $subString[10]        ; substring 1 - 10
            $runMultiplier[1] = $gameDetail
            If $i = 1 Then      ;
                $score[$j] = $subString[11]
            Else
                If  $runMultiplier[1] <> $runMultiplier[0] Then
                    $j  = 0
                    $score[$j] = $subString[11]
                Else
                    $j += 1
                    If $j >= $size Then
                        $j = 0
                    EndIf
                    $score[$j] = $subString[11]
                EndIf

                $resultLine = FileReadLine($rawResult, $i+1)
                $subString =  StringSplit($resultLine,",")  ; split

                If StringLen($resultLine) = 0 Or $gameDetail <> $subString[1] & $subString[2] & $subString[3] & $subString[4] & $subString[5] & $subString[6] & $subString[7] & $subString[8] & $subString[9] & $subString[10] Then

                        _ArraySort($score, 0,0,0,0,1)
                        ConsoleWrite("median is = " & ($score[$size/2]  & " ----- sorted array : " & $score[0]  & " , " & $score[1]  & " , " & $score[2] & " , " & $score[3] & " , " & $score[4]& @CRLF))
                        $j  = 0
                EndIf


            EndIf
        EndIf
        $i += 1
        $runMultiplier[0] = $runMultiplier[1]
    Until $i >=_FileCountLines($rawResult)

    $j += 1
    $score[$j] = $subString[11]
    _ArraySort($score)
    ConsoleWrite("median is =" & ($score[$size/2]  & " ----- sorted array : " & $score[0]  & " , " & $score[1]  & " , " & $score[2] & " , " & $score[3] & " , " & $score[4]& @CRLF))


    FileClose($openResults)
    sleep(100000)
    Return 0
EndFunc
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. AutoIt was treating the numbers as strings and was sorting it one digit at a time from left to right.

`Number()` function took care of this issue.

Comment: but where exactly did you use that number() ?